# php.ini - не включается cURL

Tags: php, curl, ini

Почему-то не включается расширение cURL, строка `extension=curl` раскомментирована, директория с расширениями указана верно. В интернете везде пишут лишь один совет: раскомментировать данную строку. В основном на форумах она представлена в таком виде: `extension=php_curl.ini`, на всякий случай пробовал в таком виде прописать, безрезультатно. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной ситуацией, что делать?

Comment: Если сайт находится на хостинге, возможно, просто на нём выключен cURL, напишите в поддержку хостинга

Comment: Как раз таки нет, использую локалку

Comment: версия пхп? сам curl точно установлен?

Comment: PHP 7.4.8, `php_curl.ini` есть в папке ext

Comment: Так у php_curl файла расширение должно быть dll.

Comment: Это если работать на винде.

Comment: Да, dll, это я тут ошибся при написании) Проблема не в этом